# How to implement SDL Button/Menu GUI with callbacks?

Tags: c++, sdl, gui

I have been reading Bjarne Stroustrup's Programming Principles and Practice Using C++ for a while now and am nearing the end of the book. I have to tried to make a very simple game using the SDL libraries as a little exercise to practice programming and utilize techniques from the book.

I've attempted to implement a rather crude GUI system that sort of resembles the one described in the book. The problem that I am having is implementing a callback system so that when a button is constructed it takes a member function as an argument so that it can be called when the button pressed. The reason why it needs to be a member function is that the game has a state system very similar to this http://gamedevgeek.com/tutorials/managing-game-states-in-c/ since I followed the tutorial when crafting my own game state system.

The existing code looks like this:

```
class Button : public Widget {
private:
    SDL_Surface* m_image;
    SDL_Rect* m_clip;
    bool m_pressed;
    bool m_released;
    int frame;
public:
    Button(int x, int y, int w, int h, SDL_Surface* img, SDL_Rect* clip);
    void handle_events(SDL_Event& event);
    void show(SDL_Surface* screen, GameState* state);
    bool released();
};

Button::Button(int x, int y, int w, int h, SDL_Surface* img, SDL_Rect* clip)
   :Widget(x,y,w,h), 
   m_image(img), 
   m_pressed(0), 
   m_released(0),
   m_clip(clip),
   frame(0)
{
}
```

So my question is: *How do you pass a function in the constructor and call it when the button is pressed?* (Like a callback). Currently each state, for example a Menu state, will just look if a button is pressed and perform a corresponding task which is pretty bad and hardly readable.

Stroustrup's code for the GUI system in the PPP book can be found here:
http://www.stroustrup.com/Programming/Graphics/
in the two GUI files.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

If you want simple callbacks, you can just use normal C function pointers. You can see here a small tutorial on them: http://www.learncpp.com/cpp-tutorial/78-function-pointers/

So, in your case you'd add a parameter like `void (*clickedCallback)()` in the ctor of the Button. Then, when it is clicked you'd call the function your saved before: `m_clickedCallback();`

Optionally, you might want to send the button which called the callback as argument. The definition/calling will become:

```
void (*m_clickedCallback)(const Button&);
// ...
m_clickedCallback(*this);
```

LE: On a second read, it seems you might want a member function (not a simple one). That is slightly more complicated, because you'd have to pass the **object** instance around when you want to call its method. More info on this topic you can find on Parashift's superb website: http://www.parashift.com/c++-faq/pointers-to-members.html.

Basically you'd need some sort of wrapper/struct that holds both the function to a member (similarly to the C one, but with the class specified) and the member instance where to call the callback function on.

Comment: ahh yes, I finally got it to work the problem was that I naively forgot that the member function to be called, needed to be static. I was sure I had tried that, but anyway it works now, thank you.

Answer (score 5):

The more modern way of doing it is by using delegates or functors.

C++11 has them built in: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/function  They're also a part of Boost if you're using an older compiler: http://www.boost.org/doc/libs/1_53_0/doc/html/function.html

Or if you want something a little more streamlined you can use something like FastDelegate: http://www.codeproject.com/Articles/7150/Member-Function-Pointers-and-the-Fastest-Possible